# What are the best practices for building an SMS server

Tags: architecture, system, gsm, sms-gateway

I am trying to build a system in which I have terminal nodes capable of sending/receiving SMS messages over a GSM network. I now need to construct a server solution which would send SMS messages acting as a gateway between a webserver holding my business logic and the clients (nodes). The communication is both ways.
I've read something about complete SMS server solutions (that act as a GSM gateway, possibly), but they turn out to be too expensive.
I've thought about attaching a mobile phone to my server (and then using some APIs), but it may be that my server will go to a data-center whereby I cannot attach anything in this way.
I do not expect to have too many messages (like 100 per day/both ways). And I do not plan to have too many clients too (less than 100).
Here I'm asking for a general system solution (e.g. best practice).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are three basic alternatives for building such an SMS server:

1) Attach mobile phones or USB GSM sticks to the server and use these for SMS communicaton. Limitations are

- Limited volumes (however your 100 SMS/day should be fine).
- Possibly rather unreliable due to consumer hardware (e.g. phone/stick firmware is not built for 24x7 operation, you may need to reset devices regularly; most mobile phones require a battery in order to function, batteries wear out).
- Possibly not placable in data centers, due to RF rules and mobile network coverage.
- Mobile number scheme limited to SIM MSISDN.

2) Connect the SMS to a network operators SMS gateway. Network operators use these exactly for this scenario: bulk SMS communication. These are proprietary and usually talk an "easier" to digest message transport protocol. Limitations:

- You are bound to the network operator, connection-wise and protocol-wise.
- Possibly delays in communication since the gateway might do store-and-forward.
- Depending on pricing scheme might make sense only for high volumes.

3) Connect the SMS server to the mobile operators SS7 network, adding it as a network element. Limitations:

- Complex implementation. Requires dedicated hardware (an SS7 interface card) and drivers to be programmed.
- Requires non-trivial network integration with network operator including extensive testing.
- Requires an E1/T1 line (or bigger, or SIGTRAN) for connection this is typically a data center thing, but not available in every data center.
- Expensive, in terms of pricing scheme and operation.

Assuming I understand your requirements, for your case I would go for option 1) and place the SMS server where it has good coverage, i.e. not necessarily in the data center. Sell it as a head-end for the server infrastructure. If putting it in the data center is a must, then go to option 2) and check out your mobile network operators SMS wholesale offerings.

Comment: This is great.
Many thanks for this.
I think I should go the 1) direction and I've already figured out how I'm going to configure it.Cheers!

Comment: Hi Bernd we are trying to build a solution based on your advice of using GSM modem. However the SMS received by the MMX144F are stored inside a database, which we are not able to read from outside. Can you suggest us some software which can store the SMS to a text file

Comment: Assuming that a MMX144F is a mobile phone or a USB stick: You should be able to read the SMS content via AT commands. If that is not possible, you may need to try with another device.

Answer (score 1):

I use smstools package in Linux to receive, parse SMS messages. In the configuration file, you point to an external script which receives 2 arguments (e.g. RECEIVED path-to-sms-file). I parse the SMSs using perl. Other option is Alamo SMS gateway, but I had many issues with it.