# Receiving SMS with GSM modem

Tags: sms, gsm, modem

I read that a GSM modem can only receive up to 30 SMS per minute. What would you do if you need to receive more than that? Is there another technology?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056903/what-are-the-best-practices-for-building-an-sms-server

Comment: Thanks Bernd. How can I mark this question as solved now??

Comment: You can answer your own question, with that link in it. Then, after a day, you accept your own answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about programming at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might want something different to those answers listed at [What are the best practices for building an SMS server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056903/what-are-the-best-practices-for-building-an-sms-server)

If you just have one service that is running where you want to receive many SMS then it would be most cost effective (and simplest) to avoid integrating with a mobile network operator and instead use a SMS aggregator. These often call themselves SMS gateways, but they are independent companies and not a mobile network operator's gateway.

An SMS aggregator acts as a middle man between you and the networks - they have agreements with many network operators and this interconnection means you can link with one aggregator and get access to almost every network in the world.

Aggregator's usually advertise for outbound SMS (where you are sending an SMS from your application to a user), but they all offer inbound SMS as well. Depending on your country you could opt for a premium number or free to receive number. A premium number would mean that the person sending the text message would pay extra money to send you a message - you may want this for a commercial service in order to bill the user. A premium number would also mean you receive a share of the money the user paid to send you the text message. A free to receive number would not cost the person sending the text message anything more than it would normally cost for them to send an SMS. Almost all aggregators will charge you a monthly rental for a free to receive inbound telephone number, but no additional charge per message received.

You can expect to integrate with an aggregator using HTTP or SMPP. HTTP is usually the easiest and the aggregator will want to know where to send the HTTP post when a message is received on your telephone number. Therefore you will need some sort of service that is running to receive the HTTP post from the aggregator, and possibly a way to reply to the user by sending another HTTP post back to the aggregator asking them to forward a message to the user confirming receipt of the inbound SMS message.
SMPP is a more robust protocol and is often used for high volume SMS applications - unless you already have SMPP experience or are sending many hundreds of thousands of messages you may want to avoid SMPP as it is difficult to implement until you have a lot of experience with SMS.

Some aggregators will provide their own platform where you don't need to have your own service running. For example you could setup a simple "autoresponder" on an aggregators website, this would receive the inbound message from the user, then autopmatically respond with a "thank you message". All interaction is done by the aggregator and you can log on periodically to download statistics or look at the messages people have sent.

Popular aggregators are:

- [InfoBip](http://infobip.com)
- [Silverstreet](http://www.silverstreet.com)
- [mBlox](http://www.mblox.com)

If you do not have your own platform for managing the SMS interaction then either use the aggregator's own platform of install your own SMSC gateway. Some SMSC's are:

- [Kannel](http://www.kannel.org) - Open Source, fairly difficult to install and manage.
- [NowSMS](http://www.nowsms.com) - Commercial software. Powerful, windows only, easy to use SMPP integration and has a 30 day free version. Allows GSM modems, HTTP and SMPP integration. Most expensive of these options but pricing is based on number of messages you want to send OUT per second / minute so if you're not planning on sending many out and only receiving them maybe this would be a viable option. There's a cheaper version where you can use one GSM modem (mobile phone) connected to a computer with a USB lead but as you will only have one GSM modem and no aggregator's you are limited to the speed at which your device can receive inbound SMS.
- [Ozeki](http://ozekisms.com) - Commercial software. Lots of documentation available and the support team are very responsive. You can add local GSM modems or aggregator's using HTTP or SMPP.