# Questions on SMS gateways

Tags: sms, gsm, sms-gateway

I need a good sms gateway which I would like to host on a server. Ive seen plenty of paid services but after building everything else for my set up Im pretty sure I can take on setting up the gateway myself with some help of course ;)

However Im concerned about the reliability of most open source sms gateways and so Im not to sure which one to start messing with. What Id like to know is if anyone here has any experience using any of the opensource gateways and if so how painful/easy was the set up and also did you end up using a gsm set up or something else?

If my question seems lacking details I appologize but I just started researching them myself. If anyone could just post a link or thought on the matter that would be great :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5056903/what-are-the-best-practices-for-building-an-sms-server/5059723#5059723) and its answers is helpful.

An SMS gateway requires a (paid) connection to a mobile network. You should understand your traffic volume requirements for selecting the right interfacing approach. The interfacing approach constrains your options for the technical platform.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to use [Kannel WAP and SMS Gateway](http://www.kannel.org) as quite mature product. It supports most popular SMSC protocols (SMPP, UCP, HTTP, CIMD) and provides simple HTTP API to services implementing business logic.

Comment: Hey thanks for the extra link :) I havent seen that set up before. Do you have any experience using Kannel for large scale operations? For example on the order of thousands of messages per hour.

Comment: From personal experience: production 500 SMS/sec, stress test 2500 SMS/sec. Kannel is really good thing for high loaded SMS applications.